# My IDE says "Errors exists in required project. Continue to launch?"

Tags: c++, arrays, eclipse, function

My IDE says "Errors exists in required project. Continue to launch?". at 48% through launch attempt. But doesn't show any highlighted errors.
Im using Eclipse indigo release 2. 
Some other user said this something similar happened to them, and that they had deleted files from their hard drive recently, which i did but nothing in regards eclipse or c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void search(char wrd2[26]);

bool srch(char wrd[26], char ch);
int pos(char wrd[26], char ch);
int cntr(char wrd[26], char ch);

void revr(char wrd2[26], char wrd1[26]);

void chcs(char wrd2[26], char wrd1[26]);

void re_ch(char wrd2[26], char wrd1[26]);

int main()
{

char wrd1[26], wrd2[26];

int  opt=0;
cout<<"Please enter two word words."<<endl;
cout<<""<<endl;
cout<<"Please insert your first word here:";
cin>>wrd1;
cout<<""<<endl;
cout<<"Enter your second word here :";
cin>>wrd2;
cout<<endl;


do{

    cout<<"Search enter 1:"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Reverse enter 2:"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Change the case enter 3:"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Reverse and change the case enter 4:"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Change your first word enter 5:"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Change your second word enter 6:"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Quit enter 7:"<<endl;

    cin>>opt;
    cout<<endl;



    if (opt==1){
     search(wrd2);
    }

    if (opt==2){
revr(wrd2,wrd1);


    }

    if (opt==3){
chcs(wrd2,wrd1);
    }
    if (opt==4){
re_ch(wrd2,wrd1);
    }

    if (opt==5){
 cout<<"Please change your first word here:";
 cin>>wrd1;
 cout<<""<<endl;
        }


    if (opt==6){
 cout<<"Please change your second word here:";
 cin>>wrd2;
 cout<<""<<endl;
        }

 }
    while(opt !=7);
    if(opt==7)
    cout<<"good bye";



}
```

Does my code seems valid to you. Again there is no signs of errors on my IDE.

```
void search(char wrd2[26])
{    bool fnd=false;
char ch;
int x=0, cnt=0;
cout<<"Please enter in a character you would like to search for:";
            cin>>ch;
            cout<<""<<endl;
            fnd=srch(wrd2,ch);
            cnt=cntr(wrd2,ch);
            x=pos(wrd2,ch);


            if(fnd==true)
            {
                cout<<"Yes! Your character was found! :) ";
                if(cnt==1)
                {

                    if(x==0)
                    {
                            cout<<ch<<" is the "<<x+1<<"st letter of the                  word "<<wrd2<<".";
                    }

                    if(x==1)
                    {
                            cout<<ch<<" is the "<<x+1<<"nd letter of the word "<<wrd2<<".";
                    }

                    if(x==2)
                    {
                            cout<<ch<<" is the "<<x+1<<"rd letter of the word "<<wrd2<<".";
                    }
                    if(x>2)
                    {
                            cout<<ch<<" is the "<<x+1<<"th letter of the word "<<wrd2<<".";
                    }

                    cout<<" There is "<<cnt<<" letter "<<ch<<" in the word "<<wrd2<<"."<<endl;
                    cout<<" "<<endl;

                }

                if(cnt>1)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                        cout<<"It first appears as the "<<x+1<<"st letter of the word. ";
                    }

                    if(x==1)
                    {
                        cout<<"It first appears as the "<<x+1<<"nd letter of the word. ";
                    }

                    if(x==2)
                    {
                        cout<<"It first appears as the "<<x+1<<"rd letter of the word. ";
                    }
                    if(x>2)
                    {
                        cout<<"It first appears as the "<<x+1<<"th letter of the word. ";
                    }

                    cout<<"There is "<<cnt<<" "<<ch<<"'s in the word "<<wrd2<<"."<<endl;
                    cout<<" "<<endl;
                }
            }




            else
            {
                cout<<"Your character "<<ch<<" was not found in the word "<<wrd2<<". :("<<endl;
                cout<<""<<endl;
            }





}



bool srch(char wrd[26], char ch)
{
int x=0;
bool fnd=false;
for(x=0; x<=25; x++)
{
    if(wrd[x]==ch)
    {

         fnd=true;
         return fnd;
         break;
    }

    }

if(!fnd)
{
    return fnd;
}

return 0;
}

int pos(char wrd[26], char ch)
{
for(int x=0;x<26;x++)
  {
        if (wrd[x] == ch)
        {
            return x;
        }
  }

return 0;
}

int cntr(char wrd[26], char ch)
{
int cnt=0;
int x=0;
for(x=0;x<26;x++)
{
    if (wrd[x] == ch)
    {
        cnt++;
    }

}

return cnt;
return 0;
}

void revr(char wrd2[26],char wrd1[26])
{
int s,x;

s=strlen(wrd2)-1;

cout<<"Your second word "<<wrd2<<" reversed added to first = ";
cout<<wrd1;
for(x=s;x>=0;x--)
{
    cout<<(wrd2[x]);
}
cout<<" "<<endl;
cout<<" "<<endl;

}

void chcs(char wrd2[26], char wrd1[26])
{
char ch;
int s,x;

s=strlen(wrd2)-1;

cout<<"Your second word with case changed proceeded by the first = ";
cout<<wrd1;
for(x=0;x<=s;x++)
 {
    if(wrd2[x]>= 65 && wrd2[x] <= 90) //is it upper?
     ch=wrd2[x]+32;
    else if(wrd2[x]>= 97 && wrd2[x] <= 122)  //is it lower?
      ch=wrd2[x]-32;
         else
         ch=1;   //invlaid char - mark with smiley face

    cout<<ch;
 }cout<<endl;
 }

void re_ch(char wrd2[26], char wrd1[26])
{
    char ch;
    int s,x;

    s=strlen(wrd2)-1;

    //cout<<"String with case changed = ";
     cout<<"Your second reversed and with the case changed procceeded by       the first"<<endl;
     cout<<" "<<endl;
    cout<<wrd1;
     for(x=s;x>=0;x--)
     {
        if(wrd2[x]>= 65 && wrd2[x] <= 90) //is it upper?
         ch=wrd2[x]+32;
        else if(wrd2[x]>= 97 && wrd2[x] <= 122)  //is it lower?
          ch=wrd2[x]-32;
             else
             ch=1;   //invlaid char - mark with smiley face

        cout<<ch;
     }cout<<" "<<endl;
      cout<<" "<<endl;
}
```

What do i do?

Comment: Well, at least at [ideone](http://ideone.com/UxLgPY) your code gives compiler errors.

Comment: Does you project include files that are not needed for this build?

Comment: Could you give me some examples? It has two files "binaries" and "includes" in the main folder and then two sub folders of "src"  and "Debug"."src" contains the main file whatever.cpp.

Comment: To use the `strlen()` function, you should also have `#include  <cstring>`.

Comment: for some reason on mac in eclipse it doesn't matter until i take the project onto PC with the IDE Devc++, then it won't let me build/run.

Comment: @NightHawk What now? IDE DevC++, or Eclipse Indigo (which is a bit outdated BTW, the actual one is Eclipse Luna)? I'd suspect you just don't have the build console selected to be shown, or have the error parsers setup correctly, to get notified by actual build errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Closing and reopening eclipse did it for me.